# setCompletionBlockWithSuccess not working

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I was trying to use the AFHTTPRequestOperation class to get data from an online php file, but I was having a bit of trouble.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]; // i have a real url in place of the ...'s
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    _data = [[operation responseData]dict];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Problem... problem.\n%@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

I tried using this code, and it wouldn't create any errors, but whenever I put a breakpoint at the `_data = [[operation responseData]dict];` line, I would find it was empty.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

P.S.: This is not a duplicate, so please do not try to mark this question as a duplicate or vote this question down; I will lose a couple privileges.

Comment: can you check responseObject?

Comment: yes; responseObject has an address.  however, i don't have an exact way to find the data inside responseObject.

Comment: Can you show the log of responseObject?

Comment: I don't really have any log of responseObject.  I used the debugger to determine the responseObject data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]; // i have a real url in place of the ...'s
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

if(responseObject)
{
    NSArray *arrData = [response allObjects];
    NSLog(@"Data = %@",arrData);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"response is empty");
}

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Problem... problem.\n%@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Hope this helps.